# ipython notebook clear cell output in code

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In a iPython notebook, I have a while loop that listens to a Serial port and `print` the received data in real time.

What I want to achieve to only show the latest received data (i.e only one line showing the most recent data. no scrolling in the cell output area)

What I need(i think) is to clear the old cell output when I receives new data, and then prints the new data. I am wondering how can I clear old data programmatically ?

Answer (score 442, accepted):

You can use [`IPython.display.clear_output`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output) to clear the output of a cell.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(10):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print("Hello World!")
```

At the end of this loop you will only see one `Hello World!`.

Without a code example it's not easy to give you working code. Probably buffering the latest n events is a good strategy. Whenever the buffer changes you can clear the cell's output and print the buffer again.

Comment: Simplest ajax interface ever!

Comment: Using the `clear_output(wait=True)` will generally make the result nicer if you have `clear_output` inside a loop.

Comment: half of the screen after the print result shakes, but shake less thanks to the wait=True

Comment: But this clears all the output. Is there a way to clear only the most recent figure? Edit: this is what I was looking for: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1744#issuecomment-335179855

Comment: Why are we looping? What's with `i`?

Comment: @jorijnsmit, just to illustrate that "Hello World!" is not printed 10 times, but just 1 time. `i` doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [IPython.display.clear_output](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output) to clear the output as mentioned in cel's answer. I would add that for me the best solution was to use this combination of parameters to print without any "shakiness" of the notebook:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(10):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(i, flush=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can have a better visualization of the function `clear_output(wait=True)` with this simple code.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time 

for i in range(10):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

If I am not wrong you mean you just need to clear the output part of a cell, which could be a valid output or some error which you don't what to look anymore. If Yes! just go to top ribbon and select **Cell > Current Outputs > Clear**

Comment: That should work for interactive clearing of the cell, but OP asked for a programmatic way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple**,
if you want to clear the output of that current cell only just use this at the end of that cell

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output(wait=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

And in case you come here, like I did, looking to do the same thing for plots in a Julia notebook in Jupyter, using Plots, you can use:

```
    IJulia.clear_output(true)
```

so for a kind of animated plot of multiple runs

```
    if nrun==1  
      display(plot(x,y))         # first plot
    else 
      IJulia.clear_output(true)  # clear the window (as above)
      display(plot!(x,y))        # plot! overlays the plot
    end
```

Without the clear_output call, all plots appear separately.