# Run Jupyter cell on page refresh

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am using Jupyter for my company's Analytics.  I want to make live page that displays some pretty charts.  I will be displaying this page on a big monitor in the lobby, and I want it to refresh automatically.

Is there some way to trigger "run all cells" by refreshing the browser page?  Alternately, is there some way to automatically run cells on a schedule?

I was hoping to find some %magic but I didn't.  Anyone know?

Thanks
P

Comment: This really isn't what Jupyter is designed for. Why not just have a Python script running on a schedule that saves static images and an html document that refreshes periodically?

Comment: I could do that, but I already have JupyterHub, and a nice document, nicely formatted etc.  I just want to display it and share a URL

Comment: Loop it indefinitely I guess, you can clear a cell programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did:

As suggested by A.R. Jupyter does not have a "Display Mode", so I set up a CRON job to run hourly

```
jupyter nbconvert --to slides --execute mynotebook.ipynb
```

and copied the generated files to a Tomcat server

Details on nbconvert found here

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to use [voila](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a project designed exactly for this purpose. This will make your analytics [look professional](https://voila-gallery.org/).

If all you care to do is just run the notebook at intervals, or with different parameters and do not care about the visual aspect, then probably [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the way to go instead.