# How to overwrite the previous print line in Jupyter / IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am fully aware of `print('Blah', end='\r')` But this does not work in Jupyter / IPython notebooks as it does in terminal it usually prints nothing or if the operation is very fast it triggers an exception. Is it just not possible?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? An error comes up or?

Comment: Fair enough. It's edited now.

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2012-April/009862.html

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code/24818304#24818304