# Printing on the same line on a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In python 3, we can easily print on the same line using the following script. I use this to understand the progress of my loop (how much time will be left). However, in jupyter it doesnt work (it prints on different lines)

```
import time
for f in range(10):
    print(f, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(10)
```

It doesnt work to turn pretty print off %pprint, and I tried the same with sys.stdout.write() but also there I have this issue.

Comment: No, the goal is to constantly print on the same line -  as an indication of the progress inside the loop ;)

Comment: I tried your solution in both a terminal IPython session and in a Jupyter notebook (Python 3.6.0 and 3.5.2 respectively), in both cases it prints on the same line, replacing what was there before it. So this does not seem to be a general issue with Jupyter/IPython.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Found the solution to this a bit later (note that it does not work in pycharm jupyter, but only in the browser implementation). For me `print` works fine, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook) `display` is advised, but it prints apostrophes around strings.

```
from time import sleep
from IPython.display import clear_output, display

for f in range(10):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(f)  # use display(f) if you encounter performance issues
    sleep(10)
```

Edit: Just wanted to add that TQDM is often also a good tool for this goal. It displays progress bars and allows you to write output below it or differ the description of each bar. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212810/tqdm-in-jupyter-notebook).

```
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

values = range(3)
with tqdm(total=len(values), file=sys.stdout) as pbar:
    for i in values:
        pbar.set_description('processed: %d' % (1 + i))
        pbar.update(1)
        sleep(1)
```

And the notebook one with nice colours

```
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook
from time import sleep

for i in tqdm_notebook(range(2), desc='1st loop'):
    sleep(0.01)
    tqdm.write(f"Done task {i}")
```

Answer (score 25):

Prefix a `\r` and add an argument `end=""` to print, like so

`print("\rThis will be printed on the same line", end="")`

This works in the Jupyter notebook in Google Colab.

Comment: Also works on databricks notebooks

Answer (score 16):

The part "\r" overwrites the line, if you leave that you append to the line. Your version `print(f, end='', flush=False)` could work but I've read under Python 3 you need to use sys.stdout.write() and best is if you add flush command too.

```
import sys
import time

for f in range(10):
    #delete "\r" to append instead of overwrite
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(f))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(10)
```

The stdout.flush is required on some systems or you won't get any output

Comment: Upvoted for not using extra libraries. It worked in JupyterLab.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the issue could arise when multiple arguments are given to the print statement.

```py
for i in range(3):
    print(i, "-", i ** 2, end="\r")
```

The above snippet prints `2 - 0 - 1 - 4` in a jupyter notebook. However, passing a single argument to `print` will give the desired result of `2 - 4` i.e. `0 - 0` is overwritten by `1 - 2` which is in-turn overwritten by `2 - 4`

```
for i in range(3):
    print(f"{i} - {i ** 2}", end="\r")
```

Here are the package versions that I am using.

```
# Name                    Version
notebook                  6.4.12
ipython                   8.4.0
python                    3.8.13
jupyter-client            7.3.4
```