# Jupyter notebook carriage return not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to print a progress bar using `end=\r` with `print()`, but the Jupyter notebook output still has new lines.

```
for i in range(0, 100000):
    print(i, end='\r')
```

Output:

```
2478
4867
6957
8970
11405
...
```

I'm running the server on Ubuntu 18.04 and am accessing it using Chrome on a Mac. How can I make the carriage return work?

Comment: Can you include the exact output you *expected* to see?

Comment: @trincot - with the '\r', each output should overwrite the previous.  So the output should be `999999`.

Comment: Could you add that information *in* the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42855972/190597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  Running in plain Ubuntu 18 / Python3 it behaves as expected.

I *guess* this is some kind of buffering issue (or a bug in Jupyter).

Based on the link @unutbu posted, it seems that only a minor time delay is needed to allow Jupyter to get its ship in shape.

```
import time
for i in range(100000):
    print(i, end='\r')
    time.sleep(0)  # EDIT, somehow even this works too.
print("")
```

Obviously if you really do have a huge amount of output (like 100k lines), this is far from ideal.  But the real delay is in the flushing and re-painting of the screen, not the actual `time.sleep()`.

If you are doing this sort of thing in a quick-repetition loop, it may be better to only update the progress-bar once every few seconds (or so).  This can be accomplished by checking for a time delta.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - maybe add a `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print?  Are you using Python3 ?

Comment: does not work in jupyter lab 1.2.3