# Why CR end="\r" works only with sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, carriage-return

I use end="\r" to print count in on the same line. My python is too fast and CR has not the time to apply. The script goes to next line...

```py
for i in range(10000):
    print(i,end="\r")
```

What it outputs:

```
3495

6735

9994

9999
```

It must outputs dynamically the number of lines, on the same line. Then 2 seconds later the outputs must be 10000 in this example...

I have no choice to add a sleep(0.01) but it slows down a lot my script. I have 8Go RAM and 2 CPU. So the script is very fast and the CR might not be taken into account ???

**EDIT**: answer is to flush.
"Printing on the same line on a jupyter notebook" solution is not working because I don't want the sleep function which will the efficiency of the script (I have 400k to 28M items)

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that this isn’t a problem with your console?

Comment: I have 8Go RAM and 2 CPU. So the script is very fast and the CR might not be taken into account ???

Comment: I don’t see what the CPU has to do with this. How a carriage return character is applied is something that is up to the console rendering the output. You could try a `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print.

Comment: @TTeaTie what is your expected output?

Comment: [This is what it looks like for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6KcC.gif).

Comment: @poke yes this is what I need. But I use jupyter notebook on a ZOE analitycs zapp

Comment: If you search on Google for “carriage return jupyter notebook”, you will see lots of discussions on that topic. It seems that it is not fully supported since *“[Jupyter Notebook] is not a terminal emulator”*. You can use other means of output (e.g. a JavaScript progress bar) instead.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649835/8353711)

Comment: @poke thanks you solved my issue with flushing. I hope it will not take too many resouces (400k lines so 400k flushes)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for i in range(10000):
    print("\r {}".format(i),end=" ")
```

Comment: not working, same issue :  3765 
 7453 
 9999

Comment: How you are running this and which console?

Comment: I run the code on jupyter notebook