# python: replace a printed line's text with another line

Tags: python, printing, console

I want to print a line and replace that line with another text.
Example code:

```py
import os
import time
lst = ["|","/","-","\\"]
num = 0
for i in range(500):
    os.system("cls") #i don't want to clear the whole terminal window.
    print(lst[num])
    if num == 3:
        num = 0
    else:
        num = num + 1
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

just like when we install a tar.gz file using pip
while building the package's setup.py it prints "building setup.py ,|,-,\" without clearing the console..

I have seen many posts regarding this.. but they all don't have a good answer..

```
SPECS:
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Python: Python 3.8.10
Arch: x86 (32-bit)
```

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565704/how-to-clear-only-last-one-line-in-python-output-console), or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python), or even this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\r` (carriage return). Also you don't need `num` as en extra variable to index `lst` you can use existing `i` to index `lst`

```py
import time
lst = ["|","/","-","\\"]
num = 0
for i in range(500):
    print(lst[i % 4], end="\r")     # i will be between 0 and 3 both inclusive
    time.sleep(0.2)
```