# Removing input() text from console Python3

Tags: python, input, formatting

I want to clear the line of text created after the input() function. I've tried \033[a, \r, end='' but either I'm doing it wrong or it doesn't work. Is there a better way:

Code is:

```
rawguess = input('Enter a 5 letter word: ')
print('words go here')
```

I've tried:

```
rawguess = input('\033[A' + 'Enter a 5 letter word: ' + '\033[A')
print('words go here')
```

```
rawguess = input('Enter a 5 letter word: ')
print('\rwords go here')
```

```
rawguess = input('Enter a 5 letter word: ')
print('\r', end='')
print('words go here')
```

And other variations of these three but nothing's worked so far.

Comment: Hello @spuddo, and welcome to StackOverflow! I think, because `input` prints a newline, you need to move the cursor up 1 line _after_ `input`, instead of in the `input` prompt text.

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console) or this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565704/how-to-clear-only-last-one-line-in-python-output-console) answer your question? It clears everything in the console though.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @JoboFernandez Tried a bunch of those, they either cleared the whole console or didn't do anything :/ Thanks for the reply though

Comment: @Bharel Windows 10

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply! Do you know what method would do that in Python 3.9?

Comment: I don't know how to move the cursor up in Windows. In most \*nix systems you can do `print('\x1b[1A')` but that's not supported by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know this before, but apparently Windows now supports [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), which include using `ESC [ <n> A` to move the cursor up (like on *nix). So we can call the Win32 API with `ctypes.windll` and enable Virtual Terminal Sequences, which will allow us to use `'\x1b[1A'`.

```py
import sys

# Only do this on Windows, so that *nix users
# can also run the program without errors
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    import ctypes
    from ctypes.wintypes import *

    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11
    ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 4

    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

    h = kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    m = DWORD()
    kernel32.GetConsoleMode(h, ctypes.pointer(m))
    m.value |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
    kernel32.SetConsoleMode(h, m)

rawguess = input('Enter a 5 letter word: ')
print('\x1b[1A' + 'words go here')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I just found a [piece of dark magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73342860/why-does-subprocess-run-enable-windows-terminal-cursor-controls-in-python) allowing you to enable terminal controls in Python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("", shell=True)
input('Enter a 5 letter word: ')
print('\x1b[1A' + 'words go here       ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick! However, I would not rely on this feature because AFAIK it's not documented anywhere... The Win32 API _is_ documented and should work with all implementations of Python.