# Python Overwrite Last Line Without Appending

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Similar questions have been answered for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python/5419488).

Building upon the answers provided I am trying to overwrite the last output line in a Spyder console using

```
interval = 1
for i in range(0,10):
    print(i, end = "\r")
    time.sleep(interval)
```

which gives me the following, unexpected output:

```
0123456789
```

If i reduce the sleep interval to something short `interval = 0.01`, then I get the output I would expect

```
9
```

How can the timing of these consecutive print statements influence what is being printed? And more importantly how do I get my pretty output?
This happens only when I use Spyder (3.2.6) and does not occur in a regular Python console.

Comment: It could just be the terminal implementation of Spyder. Where they haven't properly implemented the \r character. You say it does not happen in a regular terminal/console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know spyderimplements an IPython console, which might behave diferently. Maybe check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook) post.

Comment: Thank you, in particular this line worked for me: `print('\r', 'Iteration', i, 'Score:', uniform(0, 1), end='')`.