# Update print output from beginning of text in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, output

I want to print out various sizes of numpy arrays one after the other in a for loop, but removing the previous print at each step in the loop. A solution often suggested for strings that are less than 1 line long is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import time

for i in range(5):
    a = np.ones(i)
    print(a,end = '\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This works as the array fits on one line and thus the `'\r'` argument in the print function works fine, it goes back to the beginning of the line for the next print, so it prints `[]` then `[1.]` then `[1. 1. ]` then `[1. 1. 1.]` etc.

A problem occurs when the print is larger than one line, and with `'\r'` it just goes back to the penultimate line, like so:

```
for i in range(5):
    a = np.ones(shape = (i,i))
    print(a,end = '\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This gives the following:

```
[[1. 1.]
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

whereas I would like the arrays to update in size without overlapping on the last line. Essentially, is there a way to replace `end = '\r'` with something else so that it goes back to the beginning of the whole print rather than just the beginning of the line? I am doing this in Jupyter notebook with Python 3.8.3

Comment: Clear the screen? `os.system('cls')` on Windows, else `os.system('clear')`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel doesn't seem to work, same thing happens as described above. I'm using Jupyter notebook in case this changes something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite multiple lines in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Comment: "I'm using Jupyter notebook" -- you should have mentioned that at the start.

Comment: @Seb No, but this one did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found a solution. The key word in this was "Jupyter notebook" which allowed me to find this page:

[Overwrite previous output in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook)

This uses `Ipython.display` and the solution to my question would be written as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(5):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    a = np.ones(shape = (i,i))
    print(a)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```