# How to repositon cursor while printing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, carriage-return

I'd like to run the following code in Jupyter notebook:

```py
from time import sleep

print("Something I won't update.")
for i in range(10):
    sleep(.5)
    print("a%d\nb%d" % (i, i+1), end="\033[A\r")
```

The targeted result is the following: it prints at time `i=0`:

```
Something I won't update.
a0
b1
```

Then at time `i=1`, the three lines above are replaced by:

```
Something I won't update.
a1
b2
```

And so forth and so on...

This works properly in a terminal but not in my notebook where the ANSI escape `\033[A` is considered as an empty character `''`. In other words, in Jupyter, I get at time `i=0`:

```
Something I won't update.
a0
b1
```

And at time `i=1`, the output is updated as follows:

```
Something I won't update.
a0
a1
b2
```

**__EDIT__**

Similar questions have been raised on Stack Overflow:

[Overwrite previous output in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook)[Overwrite previous output in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook)

[How to overwrite the previous print line in Jupyter / IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956788/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-line-in-jupyter-ipython)[How to overwrite the previous print line in Jupyter IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956788/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-line-in-jupyter-ipython)

However, they only cover the cases:

- How to rewrite a single line which can be handled by:

```py
import sys
from time import sleep

print("Something I won't update.")
for i in range(10):
    sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d" % i)
```

This is not working with paragraphs (multiple lines). The behavior is the same than the one described above.

- How to rewrite the whole cell:

```py
from IPython.display  import clear_output
from time import sleep

print("Something I won't update.")
for i in range(10):
    sleep(.5)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print("a%d\nb%d" % (i, i+1))
```

Here the behavior is not the desired one as the line `Something I won't update.` will disappear. In a more practical usecase, I have other things to display like matplotlib figures that I don't want to remove.

The purpose of this question is to be able to **rewrite several specific lines**. Is there anyway to get the desired behavior in Jupyter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite previous output in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540395/overwrite-previous-output-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: `print("a%d\nb%d" % (i, i+1))` will do

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the jupyter notebook

```py
from time import sleep
from IPython.display import clear_output
for i in range(10):
    sleep(.5)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print("a%d\nb%d" % (i, i+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution is not suitable in my case (see last paragraph of my question) : I only want to rewrite specific parts of the print