# \r in Python does not delete the entire line

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a quite complex problem, but here is the "simplest version" so you can better understand it.

```
import time
for i in range(10):
   time.sleep(1)
   print('{}\r'.format(i), end="")
```

and here everything works fine, the problem comes when i try to make a countdown

```
import time
for i in range(10):
   time.sleep(1)
   print('{}\r'.format(10-i), end="")
```

the output is 10... then 90... 80... 70 and so on, it seems like if the second cipher of the 10 is not cancelled. can someone tell me why?

Comment: you said its currently printing 10, 90, 80, ...? For me it is printing 10, 9, 8, 7, 6...

Comment: @mastercool It's printing `10,90,80` etc for me. I am on ubuntu.

Comment: could it be that it depends on the python version? however i am using macos with python 3.6 on conda env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, but it doesn't "clear" anything already printed unless you overwrite it (this may be platform-dependent). Thus, the `0` character will remain visible. You can deal with that by always printing a "fixed-width" column, so that empty spaces are printed to blank out anything left over from before. You can also just put the CR in the `end` param.
Thus:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
   time.sleep(1)
   print('{: <3}'.format(10-i), end='\r')
```

This uses a [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to indicate a  space-filled, `<`left-aligned, `3`-width column. You can change the `3` to any higher number depending on how many digits your counter needs.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, i found it very useful. I found this ansi escape code on the internet... \x1b[2K\r can you explain what it does? thanks... really appreciated. alternatively, is there a method to know the width of the previous line?

Comment: @Giuppox That's a terminal escape sequence, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192019/what-does-this-mean-in-python-x1b2k). But if you're trying to do more complex terminal stuff, I'd suggest just using a proper TUI library. `curses` is the most basic and included in the stdlib, but there are a ton of alternatives out there like `blessed` or `prompt-toolkit`.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by a simple error, you are missing a space before the \r:

**Your Code:**

```
   print('{}\r'.format(10-i), end="")
   # > 10,90,80
```

**Change it to:**

```
   print('{} \r'.format(10-i), 
   #> 10, 9, 8
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, found it useful, can you explain me why? thanks, really appreciated.

Comment: this will only work fine for values less than 100

Answer (score 1):

The issue is like old typewriters when you press `\r` carriage return it goes to line start and chages one character from there. so 10 will become 90 as the first character changes.

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('{:02d}'.format(10-i), end="\r")
```

So one potential solution is to fix the width. here I have made it 2 digit