# How to print something and make it disappear after 5 seconds in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

How can I print something in Python Pandas for some amount of time?

I would like to print a statement and I want the statement to disappear after *n* seconds? How do I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: Where do you want to print it? To the console? What does it have to do with Pandas?

Comment: in Jupyter Lab :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `os` module. You'll need to define your own print function using something like:

```
from os import system
import time

def temp_print(val: str):
    print(val)
    time.sleep(5)
    system('cls')
```

Replace `cls` command with `clear` on Linux and MacOS.

**EDIT**: This works fine in console, but doesn't work in Jupyter notebooks. I'm not sure exactly how prints are handled there.

You can actually do this in Notebooks as well ([ipython notebook clear cell output in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code)) so just modify the function like so:

```
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

def temp_print(val: str):
    print(val)
    time.sleep(5)
    clear_output()
```