# Ho to clear output in Pycharm/Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Is there a function that clears the output like in Jupiter Notebooks that you can use in Pycharm or any other editors?

In Jupiter the bellow works and clears screen.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output()
```

In my code this is not working. Tried to user **clear()** from **replit** as well, but no luck.

My code:

```
import random
from hangman_word import word_list
from hangman_art import logo, stages
from IPython.display import clear_output

print(logo)

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
display = []
lives = 6

game_on = True

for letter in chosen_word:
    display.append("_")

print("Word is:", chosen_word)
print(f"You have {lives} lives. Then...dead!")

while game_on:
    index = 0
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    **clear_output()**
    if guess in display:
        print(f"You've already guessed {guess}")
    for position in chosen_word:
        if guess == position:
            display[index] = position
        index += 1
    print(" ".join(display))
    if guess not in chosen_word:
        lives -= 1
        print(f"Wrong guess. Number of lives remaining {lives}")
    if lives == 0:
        game_on = False
        print("You loose.Word was:", chosen_word)
    if "".join(display) == chosen_word:
        print("You won. Word was:", chosen_word)
        game_on = False
    print(stages[lives])
```

Comment: I think this answers your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818304/18710445

Comment: @lbherotozero for Jupiter Notebooks yes, I know this is working but for Pycharm/Visual studio no.

Comment: Maybe we can change our thinking. Can we use code coverage? This is a generic format:print("\r",object,end="",flush=True)