# In Jupyter, do you do a running update (hide) a pandas table as you are updating it?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, hide, long-running-processes

In Jupyter, I am running a long-running computation.

I want to show a Pandas table with the top 25 rows. The top 25 may update each iteration.

However, I don't want to show *many* Pandas tables. I want to delete / update the existing displayed Pandas table.

How is this possible?

[This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486642/what-is-the-currently-correct-way-to-dynamically-update-plots-in-jupyter-ipython) seems usable for matplotlibs but not pandas pretty tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clear_output` and `display` the dataframe:

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
# this is just to simulate the delay
import time

i = 1
while i<10:
    time.sleep(1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,3))
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(df)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816237/ipython-notebook-clear-cell-output-in-code
And this even more advanced usage: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1744#issuecomment-335179855