# How to show all dataframe in a list, one per line in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of dataframes:

```
type(l)
output: list

type(l[0])
output: pandas.core.DatFrame
```

I want to `dataframe.head(5)` but getting one dataframe per line in a jupyter-notebook

I can do:

```
for dataframe in l:
    print(daframe.head(3))
```

But I get all dataframes in the same line and it's pretty to read it.  Is there a better way to show all dataframes, one per line in jupyter?

dummy df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'area':['lab','class_room','pool','gardem'],'%_chance':[0.33,0.27,.30,.10]})
da=pd.DataFrame({'city':['jess','nobytown','paris','miami'],'%_chance':[0.5,0.30,.15,.05]})
db=pd.DataFrame({'country':['china','japan','france','eua'],'%_chance':[0.43,0.27,.20,.10]})
```

Dataframe's name list

```
list_df=[df,da,db]
```

This what I mean by `one dataframe per line in jupyter`:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "per line"? Can you provide a dummy expected output?

Comment: yes! just updated the question

Comment: I see, you might want to look into [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614783/programmatically-add-cells-to-an-ipython-notebook-for-report-generation), this is not really a pandas question ;)

Comment: well, i found a way:  from IPython.display import display
for l in dataframes:
    display(l)

Comment: then it's in the same cell, but glad you found what you needed ;)

Comment: yes, same cell, but prettier  than it would be tho ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using:

```
from IPython.display import display
for l in dataframes:
    display(l)
```